# better DateTime.Parse out there?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

Does anyone know of a library (paid or not) out there that is able to handle more common datetime formats than DateTime.Parse uses? Something that can handle multiple languages and abbreviations for days/months would be really nice.

For example: "Sept 1, 2009" does not work with Datetime.Parse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To parse dates with non-standard abbreviations, you'll need to create your own culture.

For example: (Tested)

```
var culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
culture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames = new string[] { 
    "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec", "" 
};

DateTime.Parse("Sept 1, 2009", culture);
```

Comment: Hmmm...that might be a way to go. Now if I could just find a predefined set of custom cultures that deal with all kinds of crazy abbreviations in different cultures.

Comment: I expected this to stop "Sep" from working, but for some reason the 3 letter abbreviations keep working even when not present in that array. (the array can only have 1 abbreviated form of each month.)

Answer (score 3):

I've used code like the following in the past (where the `expectedDateTimeFormats` are strings that follow the rules for [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)):

```
// Or use custom DateTimeFormatInfo objects
string[] expectedDateTimeFormats = new string[] {
    "customFormat1",
    "customFormat2",
    "customFormatN",
};

// You could offer several overloads here, to accept other DateTimeStyles,
// InvariantCulture, CurrentUICulture, etc. - perhaps even a collection of
// CultureInfo objects to try
public DateTime TryParseDateString(string dateString, CultureInfo culture) {
    try {
        // first, try to parse given the specified culture's formats
        return DateTime.Parse(dateString, culture);
    }
    catch (FormatException) {
        // if that fails, try your custom formats
        return DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, 
                                   expectedDateTimeFormats, 
                                   culture,
                                   DateTimeStyles.None);
    }
}
```

If you're dealing with non-standard abbreviations (like "Sept 1, 2009" as you mentioned in a comment), you may have to create a custom `CultureInfo` or `DateTimeFormatInfo` and define them yourself.

I don't know of a really good list of 'standard' custom formats (and/or related `DateTimeFormatInfo` definitions) - if anyone can find one they certainly deserve to be the accepted answer. I no longer have access to one my old team used (and wouldn't have had permission to share it anyway :( ).

Comment: This is going somewhat in the right direction of what I want. Maybe a list of these custom formats somewhere? In addition to this is the problem of different abbreviations for month names, though.

Comment: I don't know of a good list out there (though chances are good a google search will turn one up), but if you supply the culture, that should take care of the month and day abbreviations.

Comment: The whole point of this design was to allow custom formats in exactly this fashion. No new implementation required.

Comment: Use `DateTime.TryParse` instead of `try...catch`

Answer (score 2):

I also have to point out that the `DateTime.TryParse` and `DateTIme.TryParseExact` methods exist. I think it's incredibly gross that you need to worry about exceptions from attempting to convert a string to a DateTime or `<insert object type here>`.

Answer (score 1):

To handle multiple languages, you can call DateTime.Parse with different cultures.

DateTime.Parse will handle abbreviations out of the box.

If you need to handle non-standard combinations, call `DateTime.ParseExact`.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I would like a stronger implementation, though, for strings that may not follow datetime abbreviation standards for example.

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer your question.  Consider DateTime.ParseExact if you don't get an answer you like.

Comment: Apparently, you can answer the question.  :-)

Comment: I know about DateTime.ParseExact, but I'm looking for an implementation of DateTime.Parse which can figure out more datetime formats than the standard one does.

Answer (score 0):

Dont know if it has any "better" parsers, but you could check out [The Skeet's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) OS project, [Noda Time](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/11/06/noda-time-is-born.aspx)