# Not able to parse "Sept 4, 2020" or "sept 4, 2020" date string in C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, c#-4.0

I have used

```
DateTime.Parse
DateTime.TryParse
DateTime.TryParseExact
DateTime.ParseExact
```

nothing is working. Please help

Comment: Reason is that the abbreviation of September is `Sep` not `Sept`, at least in the cultures i know. Where are you from? So you either need to use a `CultureInfo` where its `Sept` or replace them with `Sep`.

Comment: It is possible to specify custom names for month, check this post:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253881/better-datetime-parse-out-there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that the abbreviation of September is `Sep` not `Sept`, at least in the cultures i know. Where are you from? So you either need to use a `CultureInfo` where its `Sept` or replace them with `Sep` in your input.

A better(than replace) option is to create a custom `CultureInfo`:

```
CultureInfo myCulture = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Clone();
myCulture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames = GetCustomAbbreviatedMonthNames();
string[] dates = { "Sept 4, 2020", "sept 4, 2020"};
string[] formats = {"MMM d, yyyy"};
foreach (string s in dates)
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, formats, myCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime dt) ? $"Valid<{dt}>" : $"invalid<{s}>");
```

---

```
static string[] GetCustomAbbreviatedMonthNames()
{
    string[] template = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames;
    // replace the september but also you might want to do it with the other months as well
    template[8] = "Sept";
    return template;
}
```

Output:

```
Valid<04.09.2020 00:00:00>
Valid<04.09.2020 00:00:00>
```

Comment: it worked. really thnx for ur response @Tim

Answer (score 1):

You can see this other post all about dates in C#: [Date Format in Day, Month Day, Year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18988921/date-format-in-day-month-day-year)

you can read this too: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Try to use:

```
string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMM dd, yyyy");
```

the output will be

as of today`s date:

```
Apr 09, 2021
```

and here is a full guide about dates formats in C#:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/date-and-time-format-in-c-sharp-programming1

Comment: This converts a date to a string, not the requested other way around. Plus it would give the full month name instead of a 4-letter abbreviation

Comment: i edited the answer to what the result will be like